# PROC GLIMMIX Simple Slopes Neg Bin

Tags: data-visualization, negative-binomial-distribution, sas

I'm attempting to plot simple slopes of my neg binomial from PROC GLIMMIX. I've been using the resources from UCLA (https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/analyzing-and-visualizing-interactions/) but have hit some snags.

My models have 6 mean-centered predictors including 2 of interest, treatment week (weeks 1-8) and affect. Neither main effect is sig but the interaction is (b = .02127, p = .02); in this case, affect is the moderator. I've used the UCLA resource to begin probing and plotting this interaction; however, I find that when I follow these steps, that I am unable to retrieve the predicted values at different levels of the interaction.

After storing the interaction, I create estimates based upon the UCLA website (I'm wondering if part of the issue is that I'm applying a basic linear regression equation to a neg bin model...)

```
PROC PLM restore = AGGBXINT;
estimate 'pred behavior_aggress, cweek = 3, ccu = 0' intercept 1 cweek 3 ccu 10 cweek*cpticu24 30 / e;
RUN;
```

Next, probing this shows me that the simple slope is sig at 1SD below.

```
Title 'Recalling INT file and testing simp slopes';
PROC PLM restore = AGGBXINT;
estimate 'minus 1 SD mod (cu)' cweek 1 cweek*cpticu24 -10.88, 
         'mean mod (cu)' cweek 1 cweek*cpticu24 .00, 
         'plus 1 SD mod (cu)' cweek 1 cweek*cpticu24 10.88 / e;
RUN;
```

The issue follows:

```
Title 'creating dataset to plot interactions';
data timeout;
do cpticu24 = -10.88, .00, 10.88;
    do cweek = 1 to 8 by 0.1;
        output;
    end;
end;
run;

Title 'Setting layout of plot';
PROC PLM source = AGGBXINT;
score data = timeout out = plotdata predicted = pred lclm = lower uclm = upper;
RUN;
```

I get the warning: At least one variable used in the model is not present or has incompatible type in the WORK.TIMEOUT score data set. All computed score variables are set to missing in WORK.PLOTDATA. I've looked all over with little success and can't find a reason why this error is occuring with my variables. This happens when I use centered and non-centered values. I'm likely making a very stupid mistake, so open to all feedback!